# How can I get "this" into scope in a ReactJS ES2015 async function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, scope, ecmascript-6

Below is a method that is within an ES2015 class.

It cannot be an arrow function because it is an async function.

But since it is not an arrow function, "this" is not in scope so I cannot do things like setstate.

Can someone please suggest how I can get this into scope?  thanks!

```
  async doSubmit(email_address, password) {
    this.setState({isSubmitting: true, error: null})
    try {
      let data = await this.props.app.server.doSignIn(email_address, password)
    } catch (jqXHR) {
      let errorType = (jqXHR.status >= 400 && jqXHR.status < 500) ? 'application' : 'system'
      let errorMessage = (errorType === 'application') ? jqXHR.responseJSON.description : jqXHR.error
      this.setState({error: errorMessage, isSubmitting: false})

    }
    // following a signin event make sure the user image changes
    this.props.app.reloadProfileImages()
    try {
      await this.props.app.initializeClouds()
    } catch (err) {
      xog('err', err)
      this.setState({error: errorMessage, isSubmitting: false})
    }
    this.postSignIn(data)
  }
```

Comment: Arrow functions can be async too. `const doSubmit = async (email_address, password) => { ... }`

Comment: @CodingIntrigue could you please point me to some defintive reference to confirm this? Everything I have understood so far says "no async arrow functions".

Comment: Sure, here is the spec which calls out the syntax for use with an arrow: https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/#prod-AsyncArrowFunction

Comment: Could you just put `this` into a local variable? e.g. `var _this = this;`

Comment: @qxz That's difficult within a class situation because you would need to store it outside of the scope of `doStuff`, but still allow it to have access

Comment: @CodingIntrigue Ah, right, forgot this was a method in an ES6 class.

Comment: Related: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Answer (score 2):

As you already use `async/await` ES7 feature you can also use *property initializer syntax* to automatically have `this` in scope. It's in the `stage-2` Babel preset.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
    doSubmit = async (email_address, password) => {
        this.setState({isSubmitting: true, error: null})
        try {
          let data = await this.props.app.server.doSignIn(email_address, password)
        } catch (jqXHR) {
          let errorType = (jqXHR.status >= 400 && jqXHR.status < 500) ? 'application' : 'system'
          let errorMessage = (errorType === 'application') ? jqXHR.responseJSON.description : jqXHR.error
          this.setState({error: errorMessage, isSubmitting: false})
        }
        ...
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <button onClick={this.doSubmit("test@email.com", "password")} />
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI `async/await` is not part of ES7 (ES2016). It will part of ES2017.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's time for me to switch naming to yearly in order to avoid off by one errors ;)

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few options. Firstly, arrow functions *can* be async, you just need to attach it to a property of the class:

```
constructor() {
    this.doSubmit = async (email_address, password) => {

    };
}
```

Here's an example of that working in the [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2017&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.prop%20%3D%20%22OK%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this.doStuff%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20Promise.resolve(this.prop)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%7D%0A(async%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20a%20%3D%20new%20A%3B%0A%20%20const%20result%20%3D%20await%20a.doStuff()%3B%0A%20%20console.log(result)%3B%0A%7D)()%3B).

If you want to keep the class declaration the way it is, you can use `bind` within the constructor to ensure the `this` reference is always bound to the class instance:

```
constructor() {
    this.doSubmit = this.doSubmit.bind(this);
}

async doSubmit(email_address, password) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Should there be the async keyword in the above example?

Comment: @DukeDougal Oops! Kind of the main point of the answer and I omitted it :) Fixed.